# How can I download a directory from S3 in parallel

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I'm try to download one directory from S3 by using transferManager.downloadDirectory(). In this directory, I have around 9000 small files.

I set 50 fixed thread pool, but I didn't feel the performance changed. I guess it only for MultiPart file download.

Is there a easy way to download directory in parallel?

```
    TransferManagerBuilder transferManagerBuilder = TransferManagerBuilder.standard();
    transferManagerBuilder.setS3Client(s3client);
    transferManagerBuilder.setExecutorFactory(() -> Executors.newFixedThreadPool(50));
    TransferManager transferManager = transferManagerBuilder.build();

    File tempDir = tempDirPath.toFile();
    MultipleFileDownload download =  transferManager.downloadDirectory("REGRESSION_TEST", fromPath, tempDir);
    try {
        download.waitForCompletion();
    } catch (AmazonClientException | InterruptedException e) {
        logger.debug("failed to download S3 files", e);
        return null;
    }
```

Best Regards,

Eric Zhang

Comment: Were you able to figure out this issue?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is there's only one thread running. 
You'd need to list all keys and then download them using **Download** rather than DownloadDirectory.